# Error while Submitting SiteMap to Google Webmaster tools?

Tags: google-search-console

I was trying to submit my sitemap to google webmaster tools but it returns the error like “ Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead. ” I am using YOAST SEO and i tried to use XML Sitemap Generator plugin for wordpress.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTYzP.png)

So how can i fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Check that your sitemap.xml file is actually properly formatted XML. You can use the XML validator here for example: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

If it's a generated sitemap file it may contain errors making it validate as HTML or other by the Google Webmasters Tools